# Minecraft launcher won't open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

When I try to open up my Minecraft launcher, a popup comes up and says `Downloading Runtime`, it only loads until there is a few mb left to load but then another pop up shows up and states that it is unable to update the Minecraft launcher. I tried restarting my Minecraft, re-installing it and updating Java but nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Java entirely?

Comment: I believe so, it said to uninstall previous java versions and i did, is that what you mean?

Comment: Kind of, but try uninstalling Java .Then afterwards, download and install the latest version.

Comment: ive done so and its still not working

Comment: I tired to just download the server from minecraft.net and it continues to act the same way

Comment: Did you try a restart of your OS after updating/reinstalling your Java?

Comment: @Ionic Yeah, rebooting your PC like what Ionic said might just work.

Comment: There are two download links on minecraft.net/download ... There is the .exe then the .msi which did you download?

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified your Minecraft version? If yes copy your current .minecraft folder(C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming.minecraft) Obviously replace yourusername with your username for windows. For Mac or Linux see the following website 
http://www.howtogeek.com/207484/how-to-find-your-minecraft-saved-games-folder/

Then reinstall minecraft and java (completely), and try it out.

If that doesn't work, you may have a problem with your PC and could have a virus. If that is what you end up with, go to the stack exchange with that type of Q/A.